# RHEL 8.8 Freezing randomly after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, redhat-enterprise-linux, nvidia

Hello apologies if this isn't the right forum to ask this on but I'm not getting an RHEL subscription, so I thought this community could help.

I am running RHEL 8.8 on my ASUS Vivobook pro 14 OLED M3401Q. SPECS: Ryzen 7 5600H Nvidia RTX 3050 Newly installed Samsung 980 SSD 16GB RAM Dualbooting Windows 11 and RHEL.

The system was working fine before I installed my Nvidia drivers which I require for Cuda processing, when it was defaulting to the integrated graphics on my CPU.

Ever since I've installed the latest-dkms nvidia driver however my screen freezes almost every 5 seconds or so. Unpredictable. Sometimes when I'm just moving a cursor around sometimes while opening new apps or settings.

Would it be possible to switch back to my integrated graphics just for my display? Would it be able to fix these issues?

Please let me know if this video is accesible and useful. Have never shared videos before so i dont know what are the best practises [Video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/RRycp7aoHcQaYK5L6)